# Why do high-reputation users get more votes?

Tags: discussion, reputation, upvotes

Recently, a user with 85.7k reputation and I (4k) reputation both answered the same question. I answered mine first, with a nice explanation of everything that was going on. He answered the question after me, and his answer was exactly contained within my answer. Why are people prejudiced for high-rep users? Shouldn't the voting be fair?

[Here is the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24197935/finding-index-in-string-with-recurring-chars/24197953?noredirect=1#comment37358093_24197953)

Comment: You might as well ask why people would read a concise answer instead of a wall of text. Of course your answer might be more useful for OP but for most users it's mostly boring.

Comment: *"Shouldn't the voting be fair?"* Since when has voting been fair? *"Why do high-reputation users get more votes?"* Because high-rep users are by definition people who have gotten more votes. You got the accepted answer on it. You also got upvotes. Why are you unhappy about the situation exactly?

Comment: If you want to write a longer answer, make sure you start it with a short version that can stand alone. Then put the long answer below it. That way, those who don't want to read the whole thing can get the point from just the first sentence.

Comment: Was it chance that you appended the bit about enumerate _after_ mgilson's solution, you should have referenced his answer if you added it because you saw his solution...

Comment: Generally, high rep users are high rep users  because they write good answers... it's a viscous circle. Have you actually objectively compared both of your answers? If you want "high" rep the quickest way is to write good answers and there's lots of people, especially in Python, who can help...

Comment: They have bigger gravity.

Comment: Cause and effect confusion: they *have* more votes because they answer well and appropriately to the question.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I happened to upvote the 85.7k user, and not yours, for these reasons:

- It was concise and directly answered the question.
- You included a menu of options without guidance as to why one option might be better than another. It seemed potentially confusing to a novice.
- It appeared above yours, which gave me the impression it was written first.

I did not consider reputations when I upvoted.

Comment: The first two are the most important. A laundry list of different techniques for achieving the same thing, without any explanation of why you would use one or the other, is just confusing.

Comment: The OP also *clearly* copied the enumerate part afterwards __without reference__ (see the edit history), granted in a slightly different (less concise) way.

Comment: Excellent explanation on all three points. It seems you note that you've realized the placement of the posts does not necessarily indicate when it was posted (unless you've sorted it that way.) That's useful to know to avoid ever making a mistake voting based on time. I have refrained from up-voting on something when it seems to rehash an answer that that had been posted a good while before... you just have to be careful you are doing so by the actual post times. Of course in this case, the time of the posts was only one of three criteria you used.

Comment: @AndrewBarber I actually never realized you could sort answers in different ways. Hidden in plain sight!